# Having multiple item types in a listview

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I'm currently working on a xamarin app with xamarin forms. I'd like to make a listview with 2 columns : the first one is a simple label but the second one can be either a label, a combo box or an entry. The type will depend on what i get from the web api.
Is there any solution?

Thanks for answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a solution can be to add in the second column (I think using a Grid) all your controls (a label, a picker....) then set the "IsVisible" Property to a X property present in your Model. If you post your Model it can be useful

Comment: Thank you, i first though about that but won't it be slow?

Comment: Why, I think no